# remove typedef from struct function pointer

Tags: function, pointers, struct, typedef

The code below works as advertised. However, I don't quite understand the mechanism of "typdef" in this application (I understand its use for the struct) so I would like to remove them to make a code comparison. I can remove the struct typedef without problems but do not understand the pointer typedef well enough to substitute it with other code. I would appreciate some help :-)

When I assign a "normal" int *ptr to the struct, the program no-longer works. It appears my problem is defining the struct ptr as a function template.

> typedef int ( *ptrToFunc ) ( int a, int b );   // would be the same as WHAT?

```
/****************************************************************
 *  Call function using pointer saved to struct                 *
 *                                                              *
 * The result:                                                  *
 *   Add:   8                                                   *
 *   Mult: 15                                                   *
 ****************************************************************/

#include "allheaders.h"                       // for me
// #include <stdio.h>                         // everybody else

typedef int ( *ptrToFunc ) ( int a, int b );  // create func ptr var

typedef struct data {                         // struct template
  int     result;                             // to store result
  ptrToFunc pFunc;                            // function pointer 
} stData;

int Add ( int a, int b ) {                    // Add two num a and b
  return a + b;
}

int Multi ( int a, int b ) {                  // Multiple two num a and b
  return a * b;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  stData     stRecord;
  
  // put desired ptr to func in struct then call function 
  stRecord.pFunc = Add;                       // func ptr var pts to Add funct 
  stRecord.result = stRecord.pFunc ( 5, 3 );  // save answer in struct
  printf ( " Add:   %d\n", stRecord.result );
  
  stRecord.pFunc = Multi;                     // func ptr var pts to Multi funct
  stRecord.result = stRecord.pFunc ( 5, 3 );  // save answer in struct
  printf ( " Mult: %d\n", stRecord.result );
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an example close enough to solve the problem [here](https://www.scaler.com/topics/can-we-declare-function-inside-structure-of-c-programming/). It was as simple as substituting the def directly (I had been attempting to assign values to a normal pointer in the struct).

This is what I needed to do...

```
typedef struct data {                         // struct template
  int     result;                             // to store result
  int ( *pFunc ) ( int a, int b );            // create function pointer 
} stData;
```